# Excel formula to compare a 6 cell row against a reference row and return value that are missing

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, comparison

I need to work out a problem I have with formula logic.

there's a picture with the exact outcome I'm trying to achieve below

i have a long list of rows that contain cells with criteria in them that are sorted in a random order, I need a formula to comb through each row and compare it to the reference row and return the values that are missing in that row when compared against the reference row.

Formulas I've tried but couldn't get working are:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(H2:M2, SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(H2:M2, Sheet2!$R$1:$W$1, 0)), ROW(H2:M2)-ROW(INDEX(H2:M2,1,1))+1), ROWS(Sheet2!$R$1:$W$1)-COUNTIF(ISNUMBER(ROW(H2:M2)-ROW(INDEX(H2:M2,1,1))+1),FALSE)+1)),"")

{=IFERROR(INDEX(H2:M2, SMALL(IF(ISERROR(MATCH(H2:M2, Sheet2!$R$1:$W$1, 0)), ROW(H2:M2)-ROW(INDEX(H2:M2,1,1))+1), ROWS(Sheet2!$R$1:$W$1)-COUNTIF(ISNUMBER(ROW(H2:M2)-ROW(INDEX(H2:M2,1,1))+1),FALSE)+1)),"")}
```

example for what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the H4 cell :

```
=CONCAT(IF(B4:G4="",B$3:G$3,""))
```

This is a concatenation of all cells values of range B$3:G$3 where corresponding cells in B4:G4 are empty cells.
Just add a space before each cell content in B$3:G$3 to separate values in the result.
Copy H4 down to others rows as needed.

Comment: Welcome to SU. This discussion-forum-type answer is a bit terse, it's been flagged as low quality and may get deleted. You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1769882/edit) it to expand a bit. [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [Help]https://superuser.com/help) gives good pointers on how to formulate an answer. In general SE sites aren't forums, but Q&A sites and work differently. It's a good idea to check the Asking- and Answering -sections in the Help and take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) to learn the what:s, how:s and why:s.

Comment: Is this better? 

Comment: Heh... your answer came up in [Review](https://superuser.com/help/reviews-intro), in low-quality queue as I said. I didn't much pay attention to the formula per se as not being well-versed in Excel I didn't understand it. Now I do - so yeah, immensely better :-)

Comment: @Bacomino Your answer is perfectly fine. At time the system can flag an answer as low quality mainly because the person who wrote it is a new contributor and also there is not much explanation given. Not every answer deserves lengthy explanation/paragraphs.

Comment: This looks like it would only work for cases where the cells in row 4 (and below) are filled in to match the cells in row 3. In the example given by the OP they are clearly filled out in a different order and not lining up at all. It's all about whether a value occurs in any of the cells in row or not.

Comment: That's true...my testing approach was to set (for example an X character) anything in 4th row because it should be quicker, clearer and simpler

Answer (score 0):

In cell H3, to help out, add this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",,SORT($B$3:$G$3))
```

This will produce a single string of all your values, conveniently sorted alphabetically and separated by spaces. This is fine as long as your six criteria strings never contain spaces. If you don't want to see it, format it so it disappears (eg custom number format of ;;;)

(If they will have spaces, then use a | pipe separator here and add some more steps at the end to remove multiple instances of || with singles, then the singles with commas)

Now for H4:
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($H$3,B4,""),C4,""),D4,""),E4,""),F4,""),G4,""))," ",", ")

This replaces each of the strings on row 4, if found in row 3, with an empty string. This leaves behind only the parts of row 3 that have not been found on row 4. The TRIM takes care of the double spaces caused where things have been removed. Finally it replaces the remaining single spaces with nice tidy comma-spaces.

Copy H4 down as far as needed